# Permutations of arrays within an array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, multidimensional-array

I am working on a project where by I need to find all possible permutations of an array.

I have this working, to a point

```
var geneticsArray = new[] { new[] { "M", "V" }, new[] { "M", "V" }};
var perms = from a in geneticsArray[0]
            from b in geneticsArray[1]

            select new { a, b };
```

This presents me with all the options:

- MM
- VM
- MV
- VV

Which is correct, but it isnt what I want to achieve, as for my intents and purposes VM and MV are one and the same.

How do I get the convert MV to VM?

This example is very simple and only contains 2 groupings, there are infinite groupings possible, which is something I will deal with later, but just want to make you aware so the reply wasnt simply reverse the result.

Any help with this would be great.

**Further Edit**

With the following code I can see a count of each permutation:

```
var permCounts = from perm in perms group perm by perm into b select new { b.Key, Count = b.Count() };
```

This will tell me each of the afore mentioned options occurs once, which is not quite right, as outline above MV and MV are, in this case, the same. I need the code to understand this.

This is what I am looking for, not how to make it able to deal with a unknown number of combinations.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this project which covers many permutation- and combination requirements: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. I wouldn't compile because of `e,f,g,h` and even if it did compile, it wouldn't work anyway, because you're going beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: @svick thanks for pointing that out, I had copy and pasted it from a larger working example, the code is now correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
        var perms = from a in geneticsArray[0]
                    from b in geneticsArray[1]

                    select new string[] { a, b };

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        foreach (var ent in perms)
        {
            Array.Sort(ent);
            var _ent = string.Join(",", ent);
            if (dict.ContainsKey(_ent))
            {
                dict[_ent]++;
            }
            else
            {
                dict.Add(_ent, 1);
            }
        }

        return dict;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do we trick:

```
var geneticsArray = new[] { new[] { "M", "V" }, new[] { "M", "V" } };
var perms = from a in geneticsArray[0]
            from b in geneticsArray[1]
            where a.CompareTo(b) >= 0
            select new { a, b };
```

Also it is easier to work with lists of different size with recursion (take a look at this post by Eric Lippert - http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/)

Comment: the example code has been updated and now will compile... copy and paste errors :(

Comment: And i thought link to Eric's post will be useful for you, but of course this post did not answer your question

Comment: Aye, now I can see that. OP wants unique permutations; Eric's code gives non-unique combinations.

Comment: @Nikolay your code will not work because you can't compare strings that way. But `where a.CompareTo(b) >= 0` should work

Comment: @SteveMallory You are right, i just though it is obvious how to do it with strings too. Fixed my answer.